# Setting PRODUCT_NAME for CocoaPods project via shell script

Tags: ios, shell, cocoa, jenkins, xcodebuild

I have a project that uses **cocoa pods**.

I couldn't set the **PRODUCT_NAME** in **xcodebuild** it always leads to compile time error.

> /usr/bin/xcodebuild 
>   -scheme $Scheme -workspace $WorkSpaceOfProject
>   -configuration Debug clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=$PathToApp "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=$CodeSigningIdentity"
>   "PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=$BundleIdentifier"
>   "PROVISIONING_PROFILE=$ProvisioningProfileIdentity" "PRODUCT_NAME
>   =$Appname"

*unknown:0: error: underlying Objective-C module 'Appname' not found*

If I remove the **PRODUCT_NAME** from the above script, then it compiles successfully but unfortunately I have to set the app name via script

I tried setting **-xcconfig** as somebody suggested , it also didn't work out.

How can I change the app name through script but at the same time compile the app with cocoa pods?

If I compile it using the project file instead of workspace it executes without any problem. Here is the script:

> /usr/bin/xcodebuild -target $Target -project $ProjectFilePathAbsolute
>   -configuration Debug clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=$PathToApp "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=$CodeSigningIdentity" "PRODUCT_NAME =$Appname"
>   "PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=$BundleIdentifier"
>   "PROVISIONING_PROFILE=$ProvisioningProfileIdentity"

But I have to compile with workspace because I am using cocoapods.

Any suggestions are highly welcome.

Comment: How do you set the variable *Appname*? Mind you, jenkins variables are case sensitive. Also, try to echo the whole call before executing it to see what xcodebuild actually gets.

Comment: Also try using the `${<variable name>}` syntax.

Comment: No No .. The problem is not about assigning the value for variable....actually value gets assigned... I have updated my question..Plz check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the above issue by using **PlistBuddy** and in the xcodebuild command I didn't use **PRODUCT_NAME**

Here is the script that I used

> /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleName test" info.plist
>
> /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleDisplayName test" info.plist
>
> /usr/bin/xcodebuild -scheme $Scheme -workspace $WorkSpaceOfProject
>   -configuration Debug clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=$PathToApp "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=$CodeSigningIdentity"
>   "PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=$BundleIdentifier"
>   "PROVISIONING_PROFILE=$ProvisioningProfileIdentity" "PRODUCT_NAME
>   =$Appname"